# How to deselect previous item and select new item in ListView

Tags: android

I am using `setSelected()` & `requestFocusFromTouch()` methods of `ListView` for selecting any item of `ListView` pragmatically. But the problem is that if an item in the `ListView` is already selected and another item is attempted to select (programmatically) then both the items are deselected as a result. So is there any way to deselect previous item (if it is selected) and select new item in `ListView` programmatically?